# Creating Numbered Pagination for Search and Filter Pro Template

Tags: php, html, css

We are using the plugin Search and Filter Pro which creates a template file for providing results. I want to change from it showing older posts/newer posts to showing numbered pagination. Im including the code that is used to create the template file. I have tried using the standard WordPress numbered pagination from https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination but none of that has worked.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Search & Filter Pro 
 *
 * Sample Results Template
 * 
 * @package   Search_Filter
 * @author    Ross Morsali
 * @link      https://searchandfilter.com
 * @copyright 2018 Search & Filter
 * 
 * Note: these templates are not full page templates, rather 
 * just an encaspulation of the your results loop which should
 * be inserted in to other pages by using a shortcode - think 
 * of it as a template part
 * 
 * This template is an absolute base example showing you what
 * you can do, for more customisation see the WordPress docs 
 * and using template tags - 
 * 
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags
 *
 */

if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
 ?>
 
 Found <?php echo $query->found_posts; ?> Results<br />
 Page <?php echo $query->query['paged']; ?> of <?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?><br />

<div class="pagination">
  
  <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
  <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
  <?php
   /* example code for using the wp_pagenavi plugin */
   if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
   {
    echo "<br />";
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
   }
  ?>
 </div>

 

 
 <?php
 while ($query->have_posts())
 {
  $query->the_post();
  
  ?>
  <div>
   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
   
   <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
   <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
     echo '<p>';
     the_post_thumbnail("small");
     echo '</p>';
    }
   ?>
   <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
   <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
   
  </div>
  
  <hr />
  <?php
 }
 ?>
 Page <?php echo $query->query['paged']; ?> of <?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?><br />
 
 <div class="pagination">
  
  <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
  <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
  <?php
   /* example code for using the wp_pagenavi plugin */
   if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
   {
    echo "<br />";
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
   }
  ?>
 </div>
 <?php
}
else
{
 echo "No Results Found";
}
?>
```